# Images broken url

Tags: magento-1.7

In CMS product images shows broken url, inspect element:

```
site.dev/media/catalog/product/c/a/catalogus-lightyears-binnen-2012-2013-pagina_001.jpg
```

this link give 403 forbidden error. I check permissions and they are good for all media folder. I use ngnix.

On the frontend, this image picks from cache folder and it's working good:

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/227x318/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/c/a/catalogus-lightyears-binnen-2012-2013-pagina_001.jpg
```

Why in CMS this images is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the server have GD library installed. Once I was facing a similar problem: I created a site on my local dev machine and than the site was uploaded to a server without GD installed and only the images in the cache were ok.
Also check these posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284767/magento-media-url-get-rid-of-403-forbidden
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597128/access-forbidden-in-magento
Best regards.

Ok, than check if your config matches this : http://www.nginxtips.com/magento-nginx-configuration.